# SQL Server left join if condition met

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem with my query. I have to do left outer join only if condition is true. If condition is false do another left outer join.

I tried with this but not successfully:

```
select 
    * 
from 
    works with(nolock) 
if work.type = 1 
begin
    left outer join 
        users with(nolock) on users.id = work.owner
else
    left outer join 
        groups with(nolock) on groups.id = work.owner
end
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please do not use `with(nolock)` - [it's bad practise](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should try left join both of them, but inside of the select, take what you want depending on the use case.

```
SELECT
  *, 
  CASE work.type WHEN '1' THEN 'a.owner' ELSE 'b.owner' END AS owner
FROM
  blahblah
  left join users on blahblah.user_id = users.id as a,
  left join groups as blahblah.groups_id = groups.id as b
```

Comment: This is maybe the best mode to solve the problem. I will try if its ok. Thank you.

Comment: Deleted my answer that isnull'ed the result, this is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query.

First method:

```
select
    works.*, isnull(users.id, groups.id)
from 
    works with(nolock)
left outer join 
    users with(nolock) on users.id = works.owner and work.type = 1
left outer join 
    groups with(nolock) on groups.id = works.owner
```

Second method:

```
if exists (select 1 from works with (nolock) where works.type = 1)
    select *
    from works with(nolock)
    left outer join users with(nolock) on users.id = works.owner
else
    select *
    from works with(nolock)
    left outer join groups with(nolock) on groups.id = works.owner
```

third method: use dynamic SQL to build query at runtime.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answar. This work. But i need do only one join with condition,

Comment: @databseCoder The second left join would be made even if the first one is true ie. work.type = 1

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you want to display all columns (`*`), then you can conditionally join against both tables by checking the `work.type` as a join condition:

```
select 
    * 
from 
    works 
    left join users on 
        users.id = work.owner and 
        work.type = 1
    left join groups on 
        groups.id = work.owner and 
        (work.type <> 1 OR work.type IS NULL)
```

A particular row from the `works` table can only have a particular value for `type`, so it will join against `users` or against `groups`, but never both. The problem with this solution becomes the displayed columns, since we are joining against both tables, now you have to unify `groups` and `users` columns.

You can do this with a bunch of `ISNULL`s:

```
select 
    works.*,
    Column1 = ISNULL(users.Column1, groups.Column1), 
    Column2 = ISNULL(users.Column2, groups.Column2)
from 
    works 
    left join users on 
        users.id = work.owner and 
        work.type = 1
    left join groups on 
        groups.id = work.owner and 
        (work.type <> 1 OR work.type IS NULL)
```

---

If you need to use the same select repeatedly, you can create a table-valued function to wrap this up so you don't have to code it every time. I'll use the table example to show another alternative, using `UNION ALL`.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetWorkData (@owner INT) -- assuming its a INT
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN

    SELECT
        -- Your wanted columns here
    FROM
        works AS W
        INNER JOIN users AS U ON W.owner = U.owner
    WHERE
        W.owner = @owner AND
        W.type = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        -- Your wanted columns here (must be same data type and order of previous SELECT)
    FROM
        works AS W
        INNER JOIN groups AS U ON W.owner = U.owner
    WHERE
        W.owner = @owner AND
        (W.type <> 1 OR W.type IS NULL)
```

You can use the function with `APPLY`:

```
SELECT
    D.*
FROM
    works AS W
    CROSS APPLY dbo.GetWorkData(W.owner) AS D -- User "OUTER APPLY" if you want works that have no users or groups
```

Answer (score -1):

You can look into Dynamic SQL. The main idea is that the SQL statement is constructed and compiled at runtime.

You can start here:
[Link 1 - MSSQL tips.](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/)

or here: [Link 2 - official microsoft documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)